# Is it possible to construct "MultiStrauss" or something like "MultiFiksel" using "Pairwise" function in R package spatstat?

Tags: r, spatstat

As the title, I am trying to use some multitype processes that can be both regulated and clustered. Thus I'm thinking of using `Pairwise` to construct interactions with marks but seems the function does not accept marks as input. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet implemented. It is on the "to do" list.

However, you can use `Hybrid` to combine several `MultiStrauss` interactions with different interaction radii, giving you a multitype pairwise interaction.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Part of my problem is that to my understanding `MultiStrauss` is always inhibitive (also `MultiHard` and `MultiStraussHard`). Are there any multitype options available (or can be constructed) that allow both inhibitive and clustering behavior? Thanks again!

Comment: `MultiStraussHard` allows the interaction parameters gamma to be greater than 1, corresponding to clustering. Similarly `Hybrid(MultiHard, MultiStrauss)` which is effectively the same thing. But you can also do `Hybrid(MultiHard, MultiStrauss, MultiStrauss)` to get multiple scales as you wish. I recommend you install the very latest version of `spatstat.core`.